# How to use gdb to debug out of bounds?

Tags: c, gdb, indexoutofboundsexception

The sample code is as following, how can I use gdb to locate the bug?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()  
{ 
   int arr[2]; 
   int a = 3;
   while(a>=0){
     arr[a]=a;
     a--;
   }

   return 1; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> how can I use gdb to locate the bug

GDB is *not* the right tool for locating this bug -- [Address Sanitizer](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer) is (Address Sanitizer will point you *straight* at the bug with little effort).

If you suspect that there is an array overflow on `arr`, you could set a watchpoint on the address just past the end of the array:

```
(gdb) watch arr[3]
```

and GDB *will* stop when the value at that address is changed.

But this requires that you *already know* that you have a stack overflow in your program, and often you don't.